# CRUD операция типа Upsert

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, c#-6.0

изучаю курс [Udemy] ASP.NET Core MVC для .NET 5.
дошёл до 54 урока и не могу продвинуться дальше. Суть проблемы:
Вместо стандартного Create и Edit задумано сделать Upsert, но при создании вываливается ошибка, которую никак не могу победить, даже заменяя свой код исходниками
Вот модель :

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }  
    [Display(Name = "Category Type")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }  
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 


}
```

}

ViewModel :

```
 public class ProductVM  
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller: GET-Upsert

```
        public IActionResult Upsert(int? id)
       {
        ProductVM productVM = new()
        {
            Product = new Product(),
            CategorySelectList = _db.Category.Select(i => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = i.Name,
                Value = i.Id.ToString()
            })
        };
        if (id == null)
        { 
            return View(productVM);
        }
        else
        {
            productVM.Product = _db.Product.Find(id); 
            if (productVM.Product == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(productVM);
        }

    }
```

Controller: POST-Upsert

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
    public IActionResult Upsert(ProductVM productVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            if (productVM.Product.Id == 0)
            {
                //Creating
                string upload = webRootPath + WC.ImagePath;
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName); 
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(upload, fileName + extension), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    files[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
                productVM.Product.Image = fileName + extension;
                _db.Product.Add(productVM.Product);  
            }
            else
            {
                //updating
            }
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View в котором исключение :
[image: исключение]

Comment: В POST-Upsert `return View();` без модели.

Comment: Автор этого курса, сделал здесь ошибку. Переводчик в рамках платформы Udemy, объясняет каждому студенту лично, как исправить этот косяк. Так что если вы легально купили доступ к этому курсу, то обращайтесь за поддержкой, но если скачали с торрента, то покупайте легальную копию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Разобрался.